# std::function's move assignment is not noexcept, but std::function::swap is. What gives?

Tags: c++

`std::function`'s synopsis in [func.wrap.func](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func) tells us

> `function& operator=(function&&);`

The move assignment operator is not `noexcept`, inhibiting its use with move only types in standard containers.

But! It also tells us that

> `void swap(function&) noexcept;`

Similarly, the default constructor is

> `function() noexcept;`

So we can implement the move constructor with a default constructor followed by a swap.

Since we can implement the move assignment operator with `swap` (`swap` has a stronger postcondition):

- how can a `noexcept` swap be implemented in `std::function`?
- why is `std::function`'s move assignment operator not `noexcept`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can a `noexcept` swap be implemented in `std::function`?

A `std::function` object doesn't necessarily contain the target directly. It may instead contain a pointer to dynamically allocated memory copy of the target. It may do this for pretty much any reason. The most common is that the target is too large to fit directly in `function`, but it's the same for anything else that prevents `function` from meeting its requirements. If the `function` only holds a pointer, that pointer can easily be moved into another `function`.

> why is `std::function`'s move assignment operator not `noexcept`?

No good reason, that's why there's a proposal to make it `noexcept` in a future version of C++: [p0771r0](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0771r0.pdf). It notes that contrary to what the standard specifies, some implementations do already mark this as `noexcept` anyway.

Comment: So basically, to make use of small object optimization, we detect if the object is small and the move is `noexcept`. Otherwise we treat it as a "large object" and put it behind a pointer, which is trivially `noexcept` moveable and swappable. That answers my question.

Comment: With small buffer optimization and a throwing move and copy contained callable, how exactly do we pull off a no throwing swap?

Comment: @Yakk We don't. We ensure we never get into that situation in the first place.

Comment: @Yakk A function object with a throwing move is disqualified from small buffer optimization. (see my comment above)